# constexpr(sizeof(T)): Why specify `constexpr` on `sizeof`?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, sizeof, constexpr

Today someone asked me to help to make a VC++ project compiling with G++ and I stumbled across this line:

```
static char data[constexpr(sizeof(T))];
```

(of course it was inside a template function with a template parameter named `T`).

I don't own a C++ standard but according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof):

> **Syntax**
>
> sizeof( type )     (1)
>
> sizeof expression  (2)
>
> *Both versions are constant expressions of type std::size_t.*

So what is the point on telling VC++ that `sizeof()` is expected to be `constexpr`?

---

Try it: https://rextester.com/VIWP36674.

Works on VC but fails for G++ as expected.

Another option to try: https://godbolt.org/z/DnioLS

Works on VC up to 19.10. Seems to be fixed on 19.14 so I conclude it was really a quirk, but even then, someone must have had a reason to write such code...

Comment: It _does_ look superfluous. On a side note: `data` may not be properly aligned for `T`.

Comment: That's not valid syntax as far as I've ever seen. By the way, the norm is to use a draft of the standard from [this page](https://github.com/timsong-cpp/cppwp). No need to own one.

Comment: @chris Agreed - but msvc [compiles it](https://godbolt.org/z/-4yD7Z)

Comment: @TedLyngmo So does clang.

Comment: @AdrianMole Which version? I updated the link to include msvc (19.24), g++ (trunk) and clang++ (trunk). Only msvc compiles it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Weird. I just went to the page you linked and selected "clang 10.0.0.0" and it worked. Now it doesn't. I think you just broke clang.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, [Not quite](https://godbolt.org/z/c8b8aW)

Comment: @chris Shh... Don't try _using_ it :-) I wonder if they used VS2017 to compile it - since I assume this was actually in code that used the function template.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Oh, [my mistake](https://godbolt.org/z/vZ4cHD)!

Comment: Right. Clang does **not** like it. Not even `clang-cl` in Visual Studio.

Comment: What's really fun is [microsoft's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constexpr-cpp?view=vs-2019) doesn't say this is a valid syntax.  Most likely this is a bug or some sort of extension I can't find anything about

Comment: have you got `#define constexpr` earlier in the code?

Comment: j4x: Can you give a little bit more context? I can compile it on its own, but whenever I try using the function template, even msvc complains.

Comment: I'm dumb, I thought MSVC rejected my original code tweak. It's gotta be a bug, right? Right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, it's an [illusion](https://godbolt.org/z/ZPoGHu). It doesn't really work. *whenever I try using the function template, even msvc complains* That's because of the non-compliant way MSVC implements templates. The template itself isn't really compiled until instantiation, it can contain all kinds of broken code and the compiler won't complain.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't find any usage of this in the STL github repo. My bad theory is that it's a bug in how `if constexpr` was implemented.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I can't add much information so I created this MRE: https://rextester.com/VIWP36674. Works on VC but fails for G++ as expected.

Comment: MSVC behaves a lot better with `/permissive-` - It's not 100%, but still... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio accepts invalid syntax in expressions including `constexpr`, `consteval` and `constinit` keywords. For example, this invalid program is accepted by the latest MSVC:

```
static_assert( constexpr(sizeof(int)) == sizeof(int) );
static_assert( consteval(sizeof(int)) == sizeof(int) );
static_assert( constinit(sizeof(int)) == sizeof(int) );
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5WqPT74ab

Submitted bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/invalid-expressions-with-constexprconstevalconstin/1626758